# Group action candidate on a set and necessity of the inverse permutation

Tags: permutations, group-actions

### I've translated a text, originally in french :

"Let $n\geq 1$, and $E$ a set.
Then $\mathfrak{S}_n$ acts on $E^n$ by :

$\mathfrak{S}_n\times E^n\rightarrow E^n$

$(\sigma,(x_1,\ldots,x_n)\mapsto(x_{\sigma^{-1}(1)},\ldots,x_{\sigma^{-1}(n)})$

The conscientious reader will check that taking $\sigma^{-1}$ is necessary to have a group action."

### What I've tried :

I've named the group action candidate $f$ such that :

$f:\mathfrak{S}_n\times E^n\rightarrow E^n$

$(\sigma,(x_1,\ldots,x_n)\mapsto(x_{\sigma^{-1}(1)},\ldots,x_{\sigma^{-1}(n)})$

To prove that $f$ is a group action, given an arbitrary n-tuple $x=(x_1,\ldots,x_n)\in E^n$, and $(\sigma_1,\sigma_2)\in\mathfrak{S}_n^2$, you must have :

- Identity : $f(\textrm{Id},x)=x$
- Compatibility : $f(\sigma_1,f(\sigma_2,x))=f(\sigma_1\circ\sigma_2)(x)$

The identity works, but the compatibility seems to fail. I derive the left member and the right member of the equality :

- $f(\sigma_1,f(\sigma_2,x))\\
  =f(\sigma_1,(x_{\sigma_2^{-1}(1)},\ldots,x_{\sigma_2^{-1}(n)}))\\
  =(x_{\sigma_1^{-1}(\sigma_2^{-1}(1))},\ldots,x_{\sigma_1^{-1}(\sigma_2^{-1}(n))})$
- $f(\sigma_1\circ\sigma_2)(x)\\
  =(x_{(\sigma_1\circ\sigma_2)^{-1}(1)},\ldots,x_{(\sigma_1\circ\sigma_2)^{-1}(n)})\\
  =(x_{(\sigma_2^{-1}\circ\sigma_1^{-1})(1)},\ldots,x_{(\sigma_2^{-1}\circ\sigma_1^{-1})(n)})\\
  =(x_{\sigma_2^{-1}(\sigma_1^{-1}(1))},\ldots,x_{\sigma_2^{-1}(\sigma_1^{-1}(n))})$

For the equality to hold, you must have :

$$\sigma_1^{-1}\circ\sigma_2^{-1}=\sigma_2^{-1}\circ\sigma_1^{-1}$$

Since $\sigma_1$ and $\sigma_2$ are arbitrary, their inverse must necessary commute for $f$ to be a group action.

### The problem:

I do not understand why "$\sigma^{-1}$ is necessary to have a group action", since it implies commutativity, and even if it was an hypothesis, I am not sure if the set of permutations whose inverse commute is still a group (maybe leading to a contradiction).

Actually, I think the group action can be defined without the inverse. It seems to me the inverse cannot work since by taking the inverse of a composition of permutations, it will swap the order of their inverse, causing the commutative property to be necessary.

Moreover by searching on the web and in books, I can see that there is a "natural group action" with the permutations which look like this one, and indeed it seems rather natural. Furthermore they do not mention constructions with permutation inverses on the the documents I read.

### Additional readings :

According to these 2 posts (in this order, the second one thinks there is a mistake in the first one) :

- [Show that $\mathrm{S}_{m} \times \mathbb{N}^{m} \rightarrow \mathbb{N}^{m}$ defines an action of $\mathrm{S}_{m}$ on $\mathbb{N}^{m}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3246143/show-that-mathrms-m-times-mathbbnm-rightarrow-mathbbnm-defi)
- [Is this a typo in a proof regarding action of a permutation group on a set?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3247173/is-this-a-typo-in-a-proof-regarding-action-of-a-permutation-group-on-a-set)

It says that $f(\sigma_1,(x_{\sigma_2^{-1}(1)},\ldots,x_{\sigma_2^{-1}(n)}))$ would not be equal to :
$$(x_{\sigma_1^{-1}(\sigma_2^{-1}(1))},\ldots,x_{\sigma_1^{-1}(\sigma_2^{-1}(n))})$$
But instead :
$$(x_{\sigma_2^{-1}(\sigma_1^{-1}(1))},\ldots,x_{\sigma_2^{-1}(\sigma_1^{-1}(n))})$$

The reasoning is the following, by letting $d_i=x_{\sigma_2^{-1}(i)}$ :

$f(\sigma_1,(x_{\sigma_2^{-1}(1)},\ldots,x_{\sigma_2^{-1}(n)}))\\
=f(\sigma_1,(d_1,\ldots,d_n))
=(d_{\sigma_1^{-1}(1)},\ldots,d_{\sigma_1^{-1}(n)})\\
=(x_{\sigma_2^{-1}(\sigma_1^{-1}(1))},\ldots,x_{\sigma_2^{-1}(\sigma_1^{-1}(n))})$

### Alternative definition :

But I can in the same way define $h_i=x_{\sigma_1^{-1}(i)}$. We have the following property :

$$h_{\sigma_2^{-1}(i)}=x_{\sigma_1^{-1}(\sigma_2^{-1}(i))}$$

Then :

$f(\sigma_1,x)=f(\sigma_1,(x_1,\ldots,x_n))=(x_{\sigma_1^{-1}(1)},\ldots,x_{\sigma_1^{-1}(n)})=(h_1,\ldots,h_n)$

$f(\sigma_1,f(\sigma_2,x))=f(\sigma_1,(x_{\sigma_2^{-1}(1)},\ldots,x_{\sigma_2^{-1}(n)})=(h_{\sigma_2^{-1}(1)},\ldots,h_{\sigma_2^{-1}(n)})=(x_{\sigma_1^{-1}(\sigma_2^{-1}(1))},\ldots,x_{\sigma_1^{-1}(\sigma_2^{-1}(n))})$

### Suspicions :

So it seems to me there is something going on, I suspect there are at least two ways to define $f(\sigma_1,f(\sigma_2,x))$ :

- $f(\sigma_1,f(\sigma_2,x))=(x_{\sigma_2^{-1}(\sigma_1^{-1}(1))},\ldots,x_{\sigma_2^{-1}(\sigma_1^{-1}(n))})$
- $f(\sigma_1,f(\sigma_2,x))=(x_{\sigma_1^{-1}(\sigma_2^{-1}(1))},\ldots,x_{\sigma_1^{-1}(\sigma_2^{-1}(n))})$

Letting $d$ or $h$ would in fact provide a choice between the constructions, which are incompatible simultaneously. A subtlety would reside in the way for $f$ to apply its first argument to the indices of the its second one.

Moreover, the author of the translated text would assume a "$d$"-construction.

### Questions :

1. Are there no errors in what I've written ?
2. Is my conclusion correct ? I.e. it is a problem of definition and hidden assumption about the construction of the group action candidate.
3. Do the author really meant the "$d$"-construct ?

Comment: [Akira's explanation](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3247340/386889) is clear and correct. Your mistake is in your paragraph "Alternative definition". There is no reason to believe that $f(\sigma_1,(x_{\sigma_2^{-1}(1)},\ldots,x_{\sigma_2^{-1}(n)}))$ equals $(h_{\sigma_2^{-1}(1)},\ldots,h_{\sigma_2^{-1}(n)}).$ There are not "two ways" to apply the definition. There is one definition, no "choice" is possible. What you call d-construct is not a choice. It is just a notation used to explain why the result of the definition is that one.

Comment: If $f(\sigma_1,(x_1,\ldots,x_n))=(h_1,\ldots,h_n)$, then why would $f(\sigma_1,(x_{\sigma_2^{-1}(1)},\ldots,x_{\sigma_2^{-1}(n)}))\neq (h_{\sigma_2^{-1}(1)},\ldots,h_{\sigma_2^{-1}(n)})$ ?

Comment: Why would it be equal? Please re-read Akira's explanation. There is only one way to apply $f(\sigma_1,\cdot)$ to the $n$-tuple $(x_{\sigma_2^{-1}(1)},\ldots,x_{\sigma_2^{-1}(n)})$. And it does not involve $f(\sigma_1,(x_1,\ldots,x_n))$.

Comment: Because If I define $a(b,(x_1,\ldots,x_n))=(x_{b(1)},\ldots,x_{b(n)})$, and then I try to compute $a(c,a(b,(x_1,\ldots,x_n)))=a(c,(x_{b(1)},\ldots,x_{b(n)}))$, how can you know if it is equal to $(x_{(b\circ c)(1)},\ldots,x_{(b\circ c)(n)})$ or $(x_{(c\circ b)(1)},\ldots,x_{(c\circ b)(n)})$ ? Doesn't it depend on how you define the way $f$ is applied to a tuple when there is a composition instead of just an integer ? I do not know an axiomatic rule which dictates how to apply a function on a tuple, and the definition of $f$ given does not seem to give an answer.

Comment: If you define $a$ by
$$a(b,(y_1,\dots,y_n)):=(y_{b(1)},\dots,y_{b(n)}),$$
and want to be consistent with yourself, you have no choice in the computation of $a(c,a(b,(x_1,\dots,x_n)))=a(c,(z_1,\dots,z_n))$ where $z_i:=x_{b(i)}$. It cannot be anything else than $(z_{c(1)},\dots,z_{c(n)})$, i.e. (since $z_{c(k)}=x_{b(c(k))}$):
$$a(c,a(b,(x_1,\dots,x_n)))=(x_{(b\circ c)(1)},\ldots,x_{(b\circ c)(n)}).$$

Comment: Similarly, you cannot escape the definition of $f$:
$$f(\sigma,(y_1,\dots,y_n)):=(y_{\sigma^{-1}(1)},\dots,y_{\sigma^{-1}(n)}).$$
Applying it to $\sigma=\sigma_1$ and $(y_1,\dots,y_n)=f(\sigma_2,(x_1,\dots,x_n))=(x_{\sigma_2^{-1}(1)},\dots,x_{\sigma_2^{-1}(n)})$ results unavoidably in
$f(\sigma_1,(y_1,\dots,y_n))=(y_{\sigma_1^{-1}(1)},\dots,y_{\sigma_1^{-1}(n)})$ i.e. (since $y_{\sigma_1^{-1}(k)}=x_{\sigma_2^{-1}(\sigma_1^{-1}(k))}$)
$$f(\sigma_1,f(\sigma_2,x))=(x_{\sigma_2^{-1}(\sigma_1^{-1}(1))},\ldots,x_{\sigma_2^{-1}(\sigma_1^{-1}(n))}).$$

Comment: I tried to construct an alternative way but it indeed is inconsistent each time. Ok, I'm convinced, thank you very much for your patience.